# Ruby regular expression utilizing OR within a character class

Tags: ruby, regex, character-class

While going through the [ruby-doc for regular expressions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html), I came across this example for implementing the && operator:

```
/[a-w&&[^c-g]z]/ # ([a-w] AND ([^c-g] OR z))
# This is equivalent to:
/[abh-w]/
```

I understand that

```
/[a-w&&[^c-g]]/
```

would equate to

```
/[abh-w]/
```

because the "^" denotes symbols that should be excluded from the regular expression.

However, I am wondering about why "z" is not also included?  Why was the equivalent regular expression NOT:

```
/[abh-wz]/
```

I am very new to regular expressions, much less any specifics for regular expressions within Ruby, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page explicitly says:

```
/[a-w&&[^c-g]z]/ # ([a-w] AND ([^c-g] OR z))
# This is equivalent to:
/[abh-w]/
```

"z" is not included in the left "AND" term, so it can't be matched.

See: "All things that are both apples, and also either apples or pears, at the same time" does not include pears. Only apples are both apples and (apples or pears). Likewise, `a` is in both `a-w` and `[^c-g]z`, so it matches; `z` is not in the left side, so "AND" is not satisfied, thus the whole expression fails.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part, I intended to say "Why was the equivalent regular expression NOT:"

I have edited the question

Comment: The rest of the answer addresses that. I will remove the now unnecessary clarification.